# Can I switch scenes by swipe gesture or drag them？

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Can I switch scenes by swipe gesture or drag them？
 In my game, there are three main scenes, each of them has several layers which have some ui elements, these elements have some tap gesture. 
This is my first time to ask question on stackoverflow, so this is the link of the picture:
[enter link description here](http://cc.cocimg.com/bbs/attachment/Fid_18/18_211485_db69684c5ee17e0.jpg)

I already know some ways to switch scenes, such as "replaceScene", or by some transitions ways, just like "CCTransitionMoveInT", so swiping scenes is feasible or not?
If not, why? 
If yes, is it possible to cause memory increases that my gameApp crash? 
Thanks men for your time.

Comment: gesture recognizer -> swipe detected -> replace scene

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I want to change screens for my gameAp at some point you can see half of both scenes at once.Sounds impossible...

Comment: use two layers in a single scene for that